# How to print this integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print a pattern for the given input as follows:
If the input is 675 then the output should be 600*6 + 70*7 + 5*5

Comment: How do you get 1174 from  3*3, 9*9 and 8*8?

Comment: Also, you need `a = int(input('....'))` to convert the string returned by `input` to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the sum of above numbers is 1774 not 1174. And such output can be generated as follows:

```
    u=a/100; v=(a-u*100)/10; w=(a-u*100-v*10)
    sum=u*u*100+v*v*10+w*w
    m=max(u,v,w)
    list=[]
    for i in range(m):
        list1=[]
        if i < u:
            list1.append(u)
        else:
            list1.append(0)
        if i < v:
            list1.append(v)
        else:
            list1.append(0)
        if i < w:
            list1.append(w)
        else:
            list1.append(0)
        list.append(list1)
    for i in range(m):
        print(str(list[i][0])+str(list[i][1])+str(list[i][2]))
    print("-----")
    print(sum)
    print("-----")
```

Comment: What kind of type error does it give? Also try solution given by @FinleyGibson. It seems more effective.

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension should be able to do this nicely.

```
a=input(" enter any three digit number ")    # first take your input as a string
a_list = [int(i) for i in str(a)]            # convert string input to list of ints

ans=0
for i in range(max(a_list)): 
    i_input = [l if l>i else 0 for l in a_list]  # create a list of zeros or a_list 
                                                 # values if the a_list value is greater than the iteration number
    i_input = [str(i) for i in i_input]          # convert back to string
    i_input = "".join(i_input)
    print(i_input)

    ans+= int(i_input)                           # convert back to int and sum

print(ans)
```

Comment: Thanks.But it prints the list, how to get the sum of this as mentioned in question? @FinleyGibson

Comment: Misunderstood question. Have amended.

Answer (score 0):

The following program works based on the fact that we can separate each number into 100*a + 10*b + c. For example, 398 = 3*100+9*10+8.

Now, we can write the total sum as 3*(3*100) + 9*(9*100) + 8*(8).

Code:

```
a = input("enter a three digit number: ")
str_list = list(a) # separates each character into element of list.
mylist = [int(i) for i in str_list] # converts each string character to int

sequence_sum = (mylist[0]**2)*100 + (mylist[1]**2)*10 + (mylist[2]**2)
print(sequence_sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it independent of the number of digits in input.

```
def patternize(num):
    l = len(str(num))
    digits = [int(d) for d in str(num)]
    tens = [10**i for i in range(l - 1, -1, -1)]
    return sum([d * t * d for d, t in zip(digits, tens)])
```